# C++ typeid. How to point deriver class?

Tags: c++, oop, types, typeid

In my project I have vector Base class type and I fill it with objects derivered classes. How can I get information about types in vector?
I've tried something like this but it doesn't work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  ~B() {}
};

int main() {

  vector<A *> wektor;
  wektor.push_back(new B);
  cout << typeid(wektor[0]).name();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 P1A
```

Comment: That's not really possible. What are you *really* trying to do? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps you should be asking about *that* instead? Please read [about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and think about how your question could be one.

Comment: A vector should store elements of a single type - you should know what that type is. Why would you need to get run-time-type info?

Comment: There are a number of possibilities here. For example, often you don't need or want to know exactly what type you have and manipulate the object through virtual functions exposed by the base class. Without knowing the underlying problem, the X-Y problem mentioned above, it is hard to make good suggestions.

Comment: Polymorphism is intended to help with reuse.  Not reuse in the sense of leveraging member functions of the base class, rather from the black box perspective of code that uses the base classes to be unaware of derived objects that fulfill the same visible API as the base class.  So ideally, the routines that handle the objects (such as `main`) do not have to "sniff" the object to see if it is of a particular type, and then take different action based on that.

Comment: Run-time type information is an expensive (and optional) feature of C++ and relying on it is often considered code smell. In almost all cases it is not needed if you apply polymorphism, encapsulation and inheritance properly.

Comment: Thank you for all answers. They are very useful and helped me to understand it better. The solution with derefercencing works but as you suggest I'll try to find better solution for my problem. Anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [C++11 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.typeid#2):

> When `typeid` is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type of the most derived object(that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers.

When you use:

```
cout<<typeid(wektor[0]).name();
```

You are calling `typeid` on a pointer. A pointer is not a polymorphic type. The object you get by dereferencing the pointer is a polymorphic type.

Hence, if you want to get the `type_info` of the most derived object, you will need to dereference the pointer in the `typeid` expression.

```
cout << typeid(*wektor[0]).name();
//             ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change:

to:

```
cout<<typeid*(wektor[0]).name();
```

it will print information about the actual type of the object, right now all it knows is that you have a pointer.

Comment: I think you have an incomplete thought here. Following "If you change:` what is to be changed is missing. This makes for a confusing read.